# How to build docker images in a lerna monorepo without publishing

Tags: javascript, docker, npm, lerna

The use case for this is branch building and deployments in Lerna monorepos.

The problem is that Lerna monorepos either hoist dependencies in NPM or use yarn workspaces to the same effect to collect all dependencies in the node_modules folder of the workspace/monorepo. Which means that they will not be accessible when building Dockerfiles in subfolders due to how docker build contexts work.

I imagine what is needed here is a kind of "lower" (as opposed to hoist) function to pull package dependencies into the node_modules of the Docker/package.json project before running docker build.

The question is, does anyone have a better idea, or know of an already existing method to do this?

Comment: Approach I used is publish local dependancies to local npm server (verdaccio) and create Dockerfile in each package need to to be built and run docker build using -f option and install each using local npm server.

Comment: That is an option I have been considering. Are you happy with that approach complexity and speed wise?

Comment: We use this method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56294568/should-a-developer-be-able-to-create-a-docker-artifact-from-a-lerna-monorepo-in/59576981#59576981

Comment: since i only need to dockerize a couple packages (and am not using yarn), i've been "tar chf ." to slurp up node_modules (dereferencing symlinks w/ the 'h' arg) and ADDing the tarball to Docker.  Its ugly and slow, but easy.

Answer (score 5):

For my own project, the solution is to use [docker BuildKit](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/) to first build all the workspace and then build a docker image for the project workspace reusing the previous built files.

In details you have copy in the docker file the top package.json with yarn lock and then cherrypicking the package.json of the needed workspace.
Then running a yarn install and a yarn build to get everything working.

Here is my project:

```
# base image
FROM @myscope/base:latest as base

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY ["package.json","yarn.lock", "./"]
COPY ./packages/server/package.json ./packages/server/
COPY ./packages/shared/package.json ./packages/shared/
COPY ./packages/app/package.json ./packages/app/

RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile --non-interactive --production=false --ignore-scripts
COPY . /app
RUN yarn build



FROM nodejs:14.15 as serverapp

WORKDIR /app

COPY ["package.json","yarn.lock", "./"]
COPY ./packages/server/package.json ./packages/server/
COPY ./packages/shared/package.json ./packages/shared/

RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile --non-interactive --production=true --ignore-scripts

# copy artifact build from the 'build environment'
COPY --from=base /app/packages/shared/dist /app/packages/shared/dist

COPY ["./packages/server/", "./packages/server/"]

WORKDIR /app/packages/server
VOLUME ["/app/packages/server/logs", "/app/packages/server/uploads"]
EXPOSE $PORT
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

`shared` is a private workspace that is a dependency of the `server` workspace.

Comment: This works fine for small workspaces, but does not scale well, since you will need to rebuild the top level docker for all changes. That becomes expensive once you have dozens of packages and projects.

Comment: @GudlaugurEgilsson, useful remark but what would you propose?

Comment: What I ended up doing was using esbuild to bundle portable upstream dependencies outside the build docker step, and bake the bundle into the image instead of letting the docker build perform npm ci/install. Then have the base container install the non-portable dependencies (db drivers, etc). This worked pretty well with around 50 containers.

Answer (score 5):

Due no answer was satisfying for me i have built an npm package, which generates a Dockerfile for lerna projects. It uses the stage feature of Docker and creates stages for each package.

## Current Version:

run thr following command to let lerna-dockerize setup all required configuration.

```
npx lerna-dockerize init
```

## Original Version:

You simply need at least two Dockerfiles:

The base Dockerfile which contains the global setup

`Dockerfile.base`:

```
FROM node:14 as base
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm i
COPY ./lerna.json ./
```

and a template for the packages

`Dockerfile.template`:

```
FROM base as build
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN --if-exists npm run build
```

you can also have custom Dockerfiles for packages by simply adding your own Dockerfile inside the package. This will replace the template by the custom Dockerfile.

afterwards you can run the command over npx to generate your dockerfile:

```
npx lerna-dockerize
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent question. For me, the whole point of using yarn workspaces was to get rid of a private npm registry.

My approach is using webpack in conjunction with `webpack-node-externals` and `generate-package-json-webpack-plugin`, see [npmjs.com/package/generate-package-json-webpack-plugin](https://npmjs.com/package/generate-package-json-webpack-plugin).

With node externals, we can bundle all the dependencies from our other workspaces (libs) into the app (this makes a private npm registry obsolete). With the generate package json plugin, a new package json is created containing all dependencies *except* our workspace dependencies. With this package json next to the bundle, we can do npm or yarn install in the dockerfile.

Setting up the webpack config took a few hours but I think it scales very well and keeps the dockerfile clean.